# Spring-Integration: Ensure that IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping is initialized

Tags: spring-integration, springfox

`IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` has a special requirement to initialize on `ContextRefreshedEvent`. To quote the code:

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    // No-op in favor of onApplicationEvent
}

/**
 * {@link HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport}s may depend on auto-created
 * {@code requestChannel}s, so MVC Handlers detection should be postponed
 * as late as possible.
 * @see RequestMappingHandlerMapping#afterPropertiesSet()
 */
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    if (!this.initialized.getAndSet(true)) {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

The effect is that its `mappingRegistry` is empty when other beans try to evaluate it during application startup, even when they implement `SmartLifeCycle` with a phase of `MAX_VALUE`.

In my case I am trying to implement a spring-integration plugin for [Springfox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/). Its `DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper` needs to access the request mappings to document them.

How can I be sure that `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` has been initialized before I start asking for its mappings? Would it be the correct approach to listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`, too, but with a high value for `@Order`? Or would you advise to use a different event?

Update: AbstractHandlerMapping already uses Order.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE. I guess I can't use the context refreshed event to be safe.

Also see the [related springfox issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2754).

Comment: Would it be an option to add an application event which fires after IntegrationRequestHandlerMapping and WebFluxIntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping have finished processing the ContextRefreshedEvent, like an event IntegrationRequestHandlerMappingReadyEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContextRefreshedEvent` is really the last step in the application context initialization:

```
            // Allows post-processing of the bean factory in context subclasses.
            postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);

            // Invoke factory processors registered as beans in the context.
            invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(beanFactory);

            // Register bean processors that intercept bean creation.
            registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory);

            // Initialize message source for this context.
            initMessageSource();

            // Initialize event multicaster for this context.
            initApplicationEventMulticaster();

            // Initialize other special beans in specific context subclasses.
            onRefresh();

            // Check for listener beans and register them.
            registerListeners();

            // Instantiate all remaining (non-lazy-init) singletons.
            finishBeanFactoryInitialization(beanFactory);

            // Last step: publish corresponding event.
            finishRefresh();
```

It is fired in that `finishRefresh()`.

You indeed should consider an `Ordered` for your own `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` with the `Order.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`. At the same time Framework register that `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` with the `order == 0` :

```
private void registerRequestMappingHandlerMappingIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    if (HttpContextUtils.WEB_MVC_PRESENT &&
            !registry.containsBeanDefinition(HttpContextUtils.HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME)) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder requestMappingBuilder =
                BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.class);
        requestMappingBuilder.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
        requestMappingBuilder.addPropertyValue(IntegrationNamespaceUtils.ORDER, 0);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(HttpContextUtils.HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME,
                requestMappingBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
    }
}
```

So, you really are save to handle mapping in your own listener. Just because, thanks to `order = 0` the `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` is going to be initialized already.

The same is applied for the `WebFluxIntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping`:

```
private void registerReactiveRequestMappingHandlerMappingIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    if (HttpContextUtils.WEB_FLUX_PRESENT &&
            !registry.containsBeanDefinition(WebFluxContextUtils.HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME)) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder requestMappingBuilder =
                BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(WebFluxIntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.class);
        requestMappingBuilder.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
        requestMappingBuilder.addPropertyValue(IntegrationNamespaceUtils.ORDER, 0);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(WebFluxContextUtils.HANDLER_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME,
                requestMappingBuilder.getBeanDefinition());

        BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerWithGeneratedName(
                new RootBeanDefinition(IntegrationHandlerResultHandler.class), registry);
    }
}
```